# Why is my AJAX function calling the callback multiple times?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made an ajax post function, and when I call it once, the callback function that is passed to it ends up getting called 3 times.  **Why is the callback being called multiple times?**

I'm attempting to use a "module" javascript pattern that uses closures to wrap like functionality under one global variable.  My ajax module is its own file, and looks like this:

```
var ajax = (function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    "use strict";

    var done = 4, ok = 200;

    function post(url, parameters, callback) {

        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if (parameters === false || parameters === null || parameters === undefined) {
            parameters = "";
        }

        XHR.open("post", url, true);
        XHR.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (XHR.readyState === done && XHR.status === ok) {
                callback(XHR.responseText);
            }
        };
        XHR.send(parameters);
    }

    // Return the function/variable names available outside of the module.
    // Right now, all I have is the ajax post function.
    return {
        post: post
    };

}(parent.XMLHttpRequest));
```

The main application is also it's own file.  It, as an example, looks like this:

```
// Start point for program execution.

(function (window, document, ajax) {
    "use strict";

    ajax.post("php/paths.php", null, function () { window.alert("1"); });

}(this, this.document, parent.ajax));
```

As you can see, I'm trying to bring in dependencies as local variables/namespaces.  When this runs, it pops up the alert box 3 times.

I'm not sure if this problem is due to the ajax function itself or the overall architecture (or both), so I'd appreciate comments or thoughts on either.

I've tried un-wrapping the main part of the program from the anonymous function, but that didn't help.  Thanks in advance!

***EDIT:***
Here's the entire HTML file, so you can see the order I include the `<script>`'s in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" conent="0" />
    <title>Mapalicious</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="js/promise.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bigmap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***EDIT 2:***

I had a typo in my example, and changed

```
(function (window, document, bigmap, ajax) {
```

to

```
(function (window, document, ajax) {
```

***EDIT 3:***

I've changed the `onreadystatechange` function to log the ready state to the console:

```
XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("readyState: " + XHR.readyState);
    if (XHR.readyState === done && XHR.status === ok) {
        callback(XHR.responseText);
    }
};
```

When I step through the code in Google Chrome, the callback is called three times, and the console logs:

```
readyState: 4
readyState: 4
readyState: 4
```

However, when I run the page as normal and don't step through it, the function works as expected and only runs the callback once.  In this case, the console logs:

```
readyState: 2
readyState: 3
readyState: 3
readyState: 4
```

So now my question is, **why is the callback called multiple times when stepping through code?**

**SOLVED:**

When I asked this question, I didn't realize that *it was only happening when I was stepping through the code while debugging*.

**So**, the state changed 3 times, but execution has been delayed by the break-point, so all 3 `onreadystatechange` functions see the current state of 4, instead of what the state *was* when the change actually occurred.

The takeaway is that `onreadystatechange` change does not store what that state is.  Instead, it reads the `readyState` *at the time its executed,* even if the program gets interrupted, and the state changes again in the mean time.

Therefore, AJAX requires different debugging techniques than you use with completely synchronous code... but you probably already knew that.

**Thanks to everyone who helped out here.**

Comment: My guess is that readystatechange event is thrown 3 times, and that by the time the first one is handled, the XHR.readystate is 4.. so all 3 call the callback.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why you might want to use something off-the-shelf like JQuery.ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is `parent.ajax` a typo? You have `(window, document, bigmap, ajax)` for params, but you're passing `(this, this.document, parent.ajax)`

Comment: Should it be `(this, this.document, parent, ajax)`?

Comment: @Shmiddty It's supposed to be parent.ajax.  In the anonymous function, I forgot to remove "bigmap" from the parameters when I simplified it for my example.  Also, I guess I could use this.ajax instead of parent.ajax?

Comment: so `bigmap` is `parent.ajax`? And the `ajax` param is undefined?

Comment: @AlanKrueger This is a _great_ example of why off the shelf libraries should be used.  I'm trying to get a good feel for how this stuff works behind the scenes, though, so right now I don't want to abstract anything away.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Looks like you were right.  Now, the only question is how to stop this from happening.

Comment: @AndrewHuth I totally understand. My first toe-dipping into AJAX involved building my own custom handlers in Javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone and couldn't do much help through that little screen. Testing code in the debugger is definitely an issue that pops up more and more once you start to really sink your teeth into the code. Closing the web inspector every once in a while is surprisingly beneficial :p

Comment: "Therefore, AJAX requires different debugging techniques than you use with completely synchronous code..." -- very valid point. I love dumping to the console, it's one of my favorite ways to debug.. especially if you know the application well... stepping through with the debugger is great for learning the application as well as debugging

Comment: +1 I fell into the same trap... your post really helped

Comment: The same for me : change() event is called 3 times on a date type input.  If you try a click() or focusout() event, it occurs only once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `readyState` has 4 distinct states:

0 - no request initialized
1 - connected to server
2 - request was received 
3 - processing
4 - Done, response received

Each of these changes will call the `onreadystatechange` handler. That's why most of these functions will look like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        //do stuff with this.responseText
    }
}
```

Just hard-code them, instead of using dodgy variables (the names `done` and `ok` seem dangerous to me).

Other than that, try declaring the `post` function either directly in the returned object:

```
return {post : function()
{
};
```

Or as an anon. function, assigned to the variable `post`:

```
var post = function(){};
```

Various engines do various things with functions, the way you declare them, hoisting them, for one. Also `post` doesn't feel right as a function name if you ask me... I'd try to use names that don't look like they *might* be reserved...

Also, you're not explicitly setting the XHR's `X-Requested-With` header:

```
XHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Which might just be what's causing the problem (HTTP1.1 and transfer-encoding chunked?)

To make debugging easier, try logging the XHR object each time the alert shows up by changing `callback(XHR.responseText);` to `callback.apply(this,[this.responseText]);`, although the argument is redundant. Then, change `ajax.post("php/paths.php", null, function () { window.alert("1"); });` to:

```
ajax.post("php/paths.php", null,
function (response)
{
     console.log(this.readyState);//or alert the readyState
     window.alert(response);//check the response itself, for undefined/valid responses
});
```

Comment: @shmiddty: Yes, so I've noticed just after posting. I read the title and was absolutely convinced that not checking the state was the problem. I've not deleted this answer because it might help others understand about the distinct states of an xhrequest - and I added some first guesses at why the alert might show 3 times

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for the good information.  I've added the the 'X-Requested-With' header.  Also, I've changed the post function to a function expression: `var post = function () {...};`.  Finally, I've changed the name I use to access the function to requestPost, so I now saw `ajax.requestPost();`.  None of these have solved the problem, but if these are a better way of writing the code, then I appreciate that.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I noticed something interesting: this problem only occurs when I step through the code.  If I just run it normally, it only runs once.  So I did what you said and logged the ready state.  When I DON'T step through the code, and it runs correctly, I get this: `readyState: 2 readyState: 3 readyState: 3 readyState: 4`.  When I step through the code, I get this: `readyState: 4 readyState: 4 readyState: 4`.

Comment: @AndrewHuth: Now that makes sense: the request can't be paused using breakpoints, so when stepping through the code, and the readystatechange callback is called for the readyState 1, and you pause on that, behind the scenes the state chanes to 2, 3 and 4. The calls to the handler get queued, but by the time you step to the next line the state has already hit 4. so the call that should have processed the readyState 2 gets readyState 4, ditto for all subsequent calls

Comment: @ahuth thanks for the hint! the callbacks will only be called multiple times when debugging...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your ajax object is returning a call to the post function.  If this is so, and you are invoking the post function on the ajax variable, wouldn't it call post at least twice: once on instantiation of the object and next on the method call?

Comment: I can only see the `post` function being called once, and since it returns `undefined` (no explicit return) I don't see what you're on about. `ajax` is assigned an object literal, that is returned from an IIFE, and that object literal has 1 property called post that is assigned a reference to a function (`post`). The op is calling it in another IIFE, and passing a anonymous function too it as an argument... nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new in using ajax, but I have the same problem that I am trying to solve. I have been reading about ajax in w3chools. I have noticed that when the state is checked, they use `this.readystate` and `this.status` **not** the `object.readystate`. I think for some reason it fires three times on `object.readystat`e and works fine with `this.readystate`. I will check it tomorrow, but I think that might be the problem.